# 複数のwarファイル間でクラスを共有したい

Tags: java, java-ee, jboss

1つのWildfly上に、複数のwarファイルをデプロイしています。
例えば、こんな構成だとします。

```
hoge.war
 - Hoge.jar
 - X-api.jar
 - X-impl.jar

fuga.war
 - Fuga.jar
 - X-api.jar
```

X-impl.jarは、X-api.jarの中にあるinterfaceの実装クラスが入っています。
Hoge.jarとFuga.jarの中のクラスは、X-apiの中にあるinterfaceを@Injectで使っています。

ここで、fuga.warはX-apiを含んでいますが、その実装を持っていません。
実装があるのはhoge.warの中です。
もちろんfuga.warの中にX-impl.jarを入れれば動くのですが、同じモジュールを重複していれることになるので、それは避けたいと思っています。
（バージョン管理の面で、片方を更新し忘れたりとか・・・）

どうにかして、X-impl.jarを1つだけにしたいのですが、可能でしょうか？
方向性としては、以下の2つのアプローチかなと思ってはいますが、いずれもやり方が分かりません。

1. fuga.warからhoge.warの中にあるX-impl.jarを参照する
2. X-impl.jarを双方のwarから取り出して独立させ、双方のwarから参照する

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. fuga.warからhoge.warの中にあるX-impl.jarを参照する

は不可能なので

> 2. X-impl.jarを双方のwarから取り出して独立させ、双方のwarから参照する

を選択することになります。
ただしこの際`X-impl.jar`だけを独立させると、`WAR`と`X-impl.jar`の依存関係が循環してしまう(`WAR`ではインジェクション対象として`X-impl.jar`が必要であるし、他方、`X-impl.jar`は実装対象としているインタフェース`X-api.jar`が必要である)ので`X-api.jar`も分離させます。

手順を大まかに並べると次のようになります:

1. `X-api.jar`, `X-impl.jar`をWildFlyにモジュールとして登録する。
2. `WAR`から当モジュールを参照できるように設定する。

この点に関わる公式ドキュメントとしては

- [Class Loading in WildFly - WildFly 10 - Project Documentation Editor](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Class+Loading+in+WildFly)
- [JBoss AS 7 / EAP 6 modules and class loading](https://www.slideshare.net/nekop/jboss-as-7-eap-6-modules-and-class-loading) (Red Hat社の方が作成された日本語スライド)

が挙げられます。また、1.のモジュール登録の具体的な手順については以下に解説があります。

- [How to install a module on WildFly / JBoss AS 7](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-as-7/how-to-install-a-module-on-jboss-as-7)

以下、[質問文に沿った形でデモコードを作成しました](https://github.com/yukihane/so40105)(※名称等、質問文と異なる部分はあります)ので、それを元に説明します。
実行環境はWildFly11/Java8です。

---

## モジュールを登録する

`hoge.war`及び`fuga.war`双方から参照する`JAR`である`hello-api-0.0.1.jar`, `hello-api-impl-0.0.1.jar`2ファイルを `$JBOSS_HOME/modules/system/layers/base/com/github/yukihane/wildfly-sharing-jar/main` にコピーします。

続いて同ディレクトリに [`module.xml`](https://github.com/yukihane/so40105/blob/master/res/modules/system/layers/base/com/github/yukihane/wildfly-sharing-jar/main/module.xml) を作成します。

## 登録したモジュールを参照できるようにする

大きく2種類の方法があります。WildFlyにグローバルな設定を行ってしまう方法と、各`WAR`で個別に設定する方法です。要件に応じてどちらか一方を選択します。

### グローバル設定

上記で登録したモジュールをグローバルモジュールとして設定します。
`standalone/configuration/standalone.xml`(※`standalone.sh`で実行する場合)を開き、
`<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:4.0">`を見つけ、そこへ次の行を追記します。

```
<global-modules>
  <module name="com.github.yukihane.wildfly-sharing-jar" slot="main" />            
</global-modules>
```

([変更差分:res/standalone.xml.diff](https://github.com/yukihane/so40105/blob/93d32b26d3bed7d0b743a56e32d1673bb81c8f53/res/standalone.xml.diff#L24-L26))

### `WAR`個別設定

`WAR`内で設定する場合、設定方法は2種類あります。 `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`ファイルに記述する方法と、`MANIFEST.MF`ファイルに記述する方法です。いずれか一方を選択します。

#### `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`方式

`hoge-war`, `fuga-war`双方の `WEB-INF` ディレクトリに [`jboss-deployment-structure.xml` を(無ければ)作成し、当モジュールの依存関係を記述します](https://github.com/yukihane/so40105/commit/e3286256f78724c2a298e80c08ffa8d023c021eb)。

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
  <deployment>
    <dependencies>
      <module name="com.github.yukihane.wildfly-sharing-jar" />
    </dependencies>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

#### `MANIFEST.MF`方式

`WAR`の`META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`ファイルに`Dependencies`セクションを追加しモジュール名を記載します。

```
Dependencies: com.github.yukihane.wildfly-sharing-jar
```

(※サンプルコードでは[Mavenのプラグインで実行している](https://github.com/yukihane/so40105/commit/e5affcea741d0bfd0dae9b5f6afe5d50c9cb1c5a)ので、確認する場合は成果物として生成された`hoge.war`等を解凍して見てみてください。)

---

Answer (score 0):

2のX-impl.jarを双方のwarから取り出して独立させるパターンで

standalone/lib/ext の下に置くか
Global Modulesを設定するのではいかがでしょうか？

https://developer.jboss.org/thread/262078

Comment: その２つの選択肢は、何が違うのでしょうか？