# EclipseからWildflyにモジュールを簡単に登録する方法

Tags: java, eclipse, java-ee, jboss

[複数のwarファイル間でクラスを共有したい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/40105/%E8%A4%87%E6%95%B0%E3%81%AEwar%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E9%96%93%E3%81%A7%E3%82%AF%E3%83%A9%E3%82%B9%E3%82%92%E5%85%B1%E6%9C%89%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84)

上記の質問にて、モジュールをwarファイル間で共有する方法を教えていただきました。
これで原理的には共有できるようになるのですが、次は日々の開発における問題が起きました。

普段、Eclipseで開発しているのですが、上記の手順で登録したモジュールも、日々修正、デバッグします。
開発対象のjarファイルの数もかなりあるので、上記手順を毎回やるのはしんどいです。
warファイルなら、Eclipseが簡単にデプロイしてくれる（Webアプリケーションプロジェクトを右クリックしてDebug→Debug on serverするだけ！）のですが、それと似たようなことはできないのでしょうか？

Comment: 所望のものか分かりませんが、Management CLI(jboss-cli)を使用すればコマンドラインでデプロイや[モジュール追加](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.0/html-single/management_cli_guide/index#add_a_module) も行えます。